# showing that two surface is isometric

Tags: differential-geometry

I tried to show that a parametrized surface $S$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ given by $(u, v)$ ->$(u, v, u^2)$ is isometric to the flat plane.

At first, I found their first fundamental form, but they are different.

(I choose a surface patch defined by $(u, v)$ -> u$\mathbb{q}$ + v$\mathbb{p}$ where $\mathbb{p}$ and $\mathbb{q}$ are perpendicular and both unit vectors.)

In presseley's text, there is a theorem following that two surface are local isometric if and only if they have the same first fundamental form.
So I concluded that they are not isometric

How can I show that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $E$ be the plane defined by $z=0$. In your case you may consider $f\colon R\to R$ defined by 
$$f(x)=-\frac{1}{4}\left(\ln(-2x+\sqrt{1+4x^2})-2x\sqrt{1+4x^2}\right).$$
Verify that $f'(x)=\sqrt{1+4x^2}$.  Define $\phi\colon S\to E$, $\phi(u,v,u^2):=\bigl(f(u),v,0\bigr)$.  It's easy to verify that $\phi$ is an isometry; check the FFFs.

I've constructed $f$ in an obvious way.

Edit (much later): The construction of $f$ is obvious since the FFF of the given map is
$$\begin{pmatrix}1+4u^2& 0\\ 0&1\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: Then, does every surface not have the 'unique' first fundamental form like the plane?

Comment: FFF depends on the parametrization.

Comment: Oh I see... In any problem such as mine requiring to show that they are isomorphic, it is sufficient to find patches whose FFF are the same.. Then. I have one more question. How do I show that two surface is not isomorphic?

Comment: Do you know something about the principal curvature?

Comment: Yeah.. But is there any relation btw principal curvature and isomorphism?

Comment: If the product of the principal curvatures of two surfaces is not the same they can't be isomorphic.

Comment: ?? Do you mean second fundamental form? I didn't hear that pricipal curvatures are related to FFF.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_curvature#Alternative_definitions

Comment: Um... This is not covered in my differential geometry class... Anyway, thanks a lot!

Comment: The way you constructed f wasn't so obvious

Comment: @MichaelHoppe how did you find $f$?

Comment: @AguirreK See my edit, please.

Answer (score 2):

I think that proof can be found on various textbook. The following one is one :

$$ {\bf x} : U \rightarrow S,\ \overline{{\bf x}} : U\rightarrow \overline{S} $$

Consider $\phi = \overline{{\bf x}}\circ {\bf x}^{-1}$. That is, $$
  d\phi (a{\bf x}_u +b{\bf x}_v)\cdot d\phi (a{\bf x}_u + b{\bf x}_v) = (a\overline{{\bf x}}_u + b\overline{{\bf x}}_v)\cdot (a\overline{{\bf x}}_u + b\overline{{\bf x}}_v) = a^2 \overline{E} + 2ab \overline{F} + b^2\overline{G}.$$

So $d\phi$ is local isometric $\Leftrightarrow a^2 \overline{E} + 2ab \overline{F} + b^2\overline{G} =a^2E+ 2ab F + b^2G \ (\forall\ a,\ b) \Leftrightarrow \overline{E}=F,\  \overline{F}=F,\ \overline{G} =G$.

Comment: What is $d\phi$?

Comment: Since $d\phi$ is a differential of $\phi = \overline{{\bf x}}\circ {\bf x}^{-1}$, so $(d\phi)_p  = (d\overline{{\bf x}})_{x} (d{\bf x}^{-1})_p$ where ${\bf x}(x)=p$.

Comment: ah.... I see. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry but I have one more question. Suppose $x$ and $\overline{x}$ are defined by $x(u,v)=(u,v,u^2)$ and $\overline{x}(u,v)=(u,v,0)$. Then they don't have the same first fundametal form, contradicting your explain. Why this happen?

Comment: If $\overline{{\bf x} }(u,v)=(u,v,0)$ then it is not local isometiric since it has different FFF. But if we set $\overline{{\bf x}} (u,v)=(f(u),v,0)$, then $\phi$ is local isometric since it has same FFF (from above article). In fact, $f'(u)\geq 1$ implies that $\overline{{\bf x}}$ is a diffeomorphism on ${\bf R}^2$. In addtion ${\bf x}$ is a diffeomorphism so that $\phi$ is isometric.

Comment: So, if I want to show that they are isomorphic, then should I choose a map $\phi$ so that the parameterizations have the same the first fundamental form?

Comment: Right. We must find a map.

Comment: I see. Always thank you for your great helps.